# PHP Warning: redis.so: undefined symbol: php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, amazon-ami

I just installed the extension as I always did

```
sudo pecl7 install redis;
```

and I got this error

```
sudo php-fpm -t
```

> [11-Jul-2019 20:52:10] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/7.1/modules/redis.so' -
>   /usr/lib64/php/7.1/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol:
>   php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0

I'm on an Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0

Comment: Depending on the OS you're using JSON is considered a "non-free" component [long story short: the guy who originated the JSON spec worded the license stupidly and stubbornly refuses to change it] so you might have to install php-json as a separate package.

Comment: but php71-json package is already installed

Comment: Installed and _enabled_?

Comment: if I put extension=json.so in php.ini I have this message PHP message: PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: The last thing that I'd suggest is to find where the existing config loads the extensions and make sure that the json extension is being loaded before the redis extension, because that seems to be the issue in literally every other instance on the first page of the google results.

Comment: not sure it is too late.  Put extension=redis.so in /etc/php.d/redis.so should solve the problem

Answer (score 5):

> redis extension must be loaded "AFTER" json extension

https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1589#issuecomment-508412700

PHP redis extension is probably loaded before json extension.

Check `.ini` files and put `extension=redis.so` after `extension=json.so`

Comment: I was checking the various files in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d`, but it was only after removing all of them and still getting a loading error that I managed to "grep" my way into finding I had somehow added it to `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`. `grep redis` is your friend :)